# I want to update my Test.js component based on localStorage change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

**Fails to run first if condition.** 
So once component is loaded it shows  "Student Progress related Stats" and when once topic-link is set(in some other component **which is removed too properly**) it shows second display. **Everything works fine till now** but when topic-link is removed if fails to run first if condition and shows second display still. Basically I want to change my component view based on topic-link is there or not.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {getQuestionsList} from '../../store/actions/questionActions';

class Test extends Component {

    render(){            
        let display;
        let topicLink = localStorage.getItem('topic-link');

        if(!topicLink){
            display = 
                <div style={{textAlign:'center',
                            fontSize:'22px'}}>
                    <p>Student Progress related Stats</p>
                </div>
        }
        else if(topicLink){
            display = 
                this.props.questions.map(question => (
                    <div key={question.id} style={{border:'1px solid #000',marginBottom:'15px'}}>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: question.direction}} />
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: question.question}} />
                        <div>
                            <form>
                                <input type="radio" name="option" value="(A)"/>{question.option_a}<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="option" value="(B)"/>{question.option_b}<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="option" value="(C)"/>{question.option_c}<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="option" value="(D)"/>{question.option_d}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
        }
            
        return (
            <div>
                {display}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        questions: state.questions.items,
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getQuestionsList})(Test);
```

Comment: Updating local storage will not trigger React to render.

Comment: But when topic-link changes the component updates accordingly

Comment: is the localStorage changes you are expecting to happen will be from the same tab ?

Comment: @ChandranshuKumar You haven't shown that code, but something *else* (`setState` or `forceUpdate`) is causing the re-render in that case. Setting `localStorage` itself won't cause re-render. The next time it renders it will get the right value from `localStorage`. It's also possible that however you are clearing the value isn't correct. Show the other code and I might be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here where i set the localStorage. On Every onTopicClick I get the desired output(meaning second if statement runs and it updates the component). Only when localStorage is removed it stays on the second if statement which not be the case(it should run first if statement). I have two fucntions(in seperate components) like onSectionClick and onTopicClick like this:

```js
onTopicClick = () => {

        this.props.getQuestionsList(this.props.topicId);

        let topicName = this.props.name;
        topicName = topicName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        let topicLink = "/updates/daily-practice-questions/" + this.props.sectionName + "/" + topicName;
        this.props.history.push(topicLink);
        localStorage.setItem('topic-link', topicLink);
    }
    
onSectionClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isOpened: !prevState.isOpened
        }));
        let sectionName = this.props.name;
        sectionName = sectionName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        this.setState({sectionName: sectionName});
        this.props.history.push("/updates/daily-practice-questions/" + sectionName);
        if(this.state.isOpened){
            this.props.history.push("/updates/daily-practice-questions");
            localStorage.removeItem('topic-link')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the hardest topics in data communication probably.

`let topicLink = localStorage.getItem('topic-link');` This line is the money line. Basically, you already identified the driver of this component, for instance, `topicLink`.

The next thing is to make sure this component use this variable as a prop input. I noticed you are using redux already, therefore this variable could be part of the state variables there.

- Next step will be to see if your store can update this variable from localStorage. This probably is another topic, for instance, check the localStorage every 5 seconds, and then update the store variable.
- However, it's not a good idea to sync components via a localStorage variable, instead, you should bootstrap your code and save this localStorage variable as a state variable first and store in your redux for example.

So either way, input prop is the first step to go, it'll help you test the code as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to store it in redux and let you know if it works.